# "Put on a show" vs. "put on an act". What's the difference?

Tags: expressions, nuance

What's the difference between "put on a show" and "put on an act"? Are they interchangeable? They look similar in meaning to me. Is there any nuanced difference?

Examples sentences from dictionaries:

1. They put on a show of affection for the sake of the children.
2. Be natural. Don’t feel you have to put on an act.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to realize here is that 'put on a show/act' aren't different idioms, they are manifestations of the same phrasal verb:

From [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/put):

> Put on (sense 5.1) - Behave deceptively:
>
> she doesn’t feel she has to ***put on an act***

There is a subtle difference. 'Put on a show' is also widely used without the negative connotations, in the more literal sense of organizing something grand. See [this](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HeyLetsPutOnAShow).